# Looking for a Macro to pull Table Titles/Headers AND the contents of each table from a Word document into Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am looking for a Macro to export the contents of every table in a Word document(s) and move this content to Excel. Along with pulling the contents of the tables however, I would like the titles of each of these tables to be exported as well. The Word document(s) are formatted in a table of contents style, with the "titles" of the tables being the headers of each section of the table of contents. Some of the sections in the table of contents have no table within the section, in which case, I would like the macro to move on from that section if there is no table within it. I am trying to have this Macro work for multiple Word documents in a single folder. The great news is that I already have a Macro currently working that does everything I asked above EXCEPT for pull the title of each table section. Below is the Macro I am currently using. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
Sub import_word_table_to_excel()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim fldpath
    Dim fld, fil As Object
    Dim appWord As Word.Application
    Dim docWord As Word.Document
    Dim tableWord As Word.Table
    Dim sdoc As String

    ' use to choose the folder having word documents
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Title = "Choose Folder"
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
    fldpath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set fld = fso.getfolder(fldpath)

    Set appWord = New Word.Application
    appWord.Visible = True
    For Each fil In fld.Files
        ' browse word documents in a folder
        If UCase(Right(fil.Path, 4)) = UCase(".doc") Or UCase(Right(fil.Path, 5)) = UCase(".docx") Then
            Set docWord = appWord.Documents.Open(fil.Path)
            For Each tableWord In docWord.Tables
                ' copy word tables
                tableWord.Range.Copy
                ' paste it on sheet 1 of excel file
                Sheets(1).Paste Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Next

            docWord.Close
        End If
    Next fil

    appWord.Quit
    Sheets(1).Select
    Set tableWord = Nothing
    Set docWord = Nothing
    Set appWord = Nothing

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: please check out [mcve] :-)

Comment: How about `tableWord.Title.Copy`? as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/table-title-property-word

Comment: Yes I had seen this page but wasn't sure of the exact process to implement it into the VBA Macro so it would copy the titles of the tables and correctly name them, while also passing over any titles/table of content sections that do not contain a table.

Comment: I think the answer is all about the structure of the document. We need to know if your section is `.Section object`, if your header is a `paragraphs(1) object` of the section, or if the only option is to check of style reference to get title. Just suggestion at this point- instead of looping through `Tables` try to loop through `Sections`. Next try to use object hierarchy to get to tables: `Section.Range.Table`. Next think of paragraphs instead of titles to get what you need.

Comment: Kazimierz, thanks for the reply. My supervisor at my job has suggested that I start by looping through sections as well. I think the titles/headers of the sections are .Sectionobject, as there are paragraphs with miscellaneous info in-between each section header and the underlying table (I would hope to be able to rid these paragraphs with the Macro as well, and just pull the Section Title/Header and the underlying tables.)

Comment: Very stuck right now on how to get the Macro to start looping through Sections instead of tables to begin with?